# Jackson custom serializer to use in Optional<?>

Tags: java, json, jackson

Say I have a simple String custom serializer and deserializer.

```
public class SimpleSerializer extends StdSerializer<String> {

  protected SimpleSerializer() {
    super(String.class);
  }

  @Override
  public void serialize(String value, JsonGenerator gen, SerializerProvider provider) throws IOException {
    if (value == null) {
      return;
    }

    value = doThings(value);
    gen.writeString(value);
  }
}
```

I use this on various `String` fields but now I need to use it on an `Optional<String>` field too.

```
@JsonSerialize(using = SimpleSerializer.class)
@JsonDeserialize(using = SimpleDeserializer.class)
private Optional<String> item;
```

This doesn't work unfortunately since the class does not match. And I can't assign it like `Optional<@JsonSerialize... String> item` because the annotation is not marked with `TYPE_USE` target. I tried creating custom annotation with `TYPE_USE`, `@JacksonAnnotationsInside` and the others as a workaround but that didn't work either, which is not a surprise.

Is there any way that I can use the serializer and the deserializer without creating another one for specifically `Optional<String>`?

Comment: Note that the usual advice here will be "don't use Optional, use a bare property".

Comment: There is no way using generics to accept a variety of types. I see why you do not want to create another Serializer as inside the Optional could be a string, but they are different objects at the end of the day. 

Also yes, as the above comment says, Optionals are not generally used as fields.

Comment: Ah yes, the mandatory advice. I'm familiar with it :).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, include the Jackson `Module` for `Optional`. It's part of

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jdk8</artifactId>
    <version>${jackson.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

Second, register it with your `ObjectMapper`

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.registerModule(new Jdk8Module());
```

Finally, annotate your field with with [`@JsonSerialize`](https://javadoc.io/doc/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-databind/2.9.7/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/annotation/JsonSerialize.html) and [`@JsonDeserialize`](https://javadoc.io/doc/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-databind/2.9.7/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/annotation/JsonDeserialize.html) but use their [`contentUsing`](https://javadoc.io/doc/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-databind/2.9.7/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/annotation/JsonSerialize.html#contentUsing()) element to specify your custom serializer/deserializer

```
@JsonSerialize(contentUsing = SimpleSerializer.class)
@JsonDeserialize(contentUsing = SimpleDeserializer.class)
```

The `JsonSerializer` used to serialize `Optional` fields, `OptionalSerializer`, will know to delegate to `SimpleSerializer` to perform the actual serialization. The same behavior applies to deserialization.